# Custom color Action Bar android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-actionbar

How to setup color Action Bar android react native?

img:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code so we can help you with any issues you have.

Comment: Added image from link

Answer (score 0):

[image: Refer this image]

it describe all thing related theme